# How Can I Remove White Space In String Array?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to form a list with the items in arrayOf. However, when I toList().toString that strArray between each item there is a white space that I am trying to get rid of. As you can see in the picture below; when I use replace( " ", "") it takes care of that, but it's also removing the white space between Item and the number. How can I remove the white space between each item without removing the white space between the item and number? If you look at the picture below; the logcat lists correctly, but there's no space between Item1 and the rest of the items. I want it to show Item 1 and so on. I've been doing trial and error for 2 hours, and I have been doing some researches online, and I can't seem to find a solution. I appreciate the help! Thanks!

[White Space Result Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIOI9.png)

Here is my code...

```
private fun strArrayInListForm() {
        val strArray = arrayOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5")
        val splitItems: String = strArray.toList().toString()
        val getItems: String = splitItems.split(",").joinToString("\n")
            .replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
            .replace(" ", "")
        println(getItems)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should replace the ", " with "\n" directly after your toString() instead of splitting by "," and all that, like this:

```
val strArray = arrayOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5")
val splitItems: String = strArray.toList().toString().replace(", ", "\n")
val getItems: String = splitItems
        .replace("[", "").replace("]", "")     
println(getItems)
```

Comment: Nicely answered! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can trim the strings in the list before converting it to a string and then joining with a newline delimiter.